# Linking with llvm clang llvm ld main not found

Tags: llvm

```
$ cat test.c
int printf(const char *, ...);
int main() { printf("ok\n");}

$ clang -c test.c
$ llvm-ld test.o -o test /usr/lib/crt1.o -lSystem
$ ./test
'main' function not found in module.
$ ld test.o -o test /usr/lib/crt1.o -lSystem
$ ./test
ok
```

I am trying to compile the simple program with clang, and then link it with llvm-ld, my goal is to avoid GNU ld. I must be using it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

`llvm-ld` uses bitcode files as inputs to either get an executable or combine all input files into a new bitcode file. For object files you need to use `lld`.